# What does "so much" modify?

Tags: modifiers

The original:

> The more Frenchmen killed in North Africa, the less popular the
>   government at home would be, so if foreign cannon fodder **was available
>   so much the better.**

Is it equivalent to?

> The more Frenchmen killed in North Africa, the less popular the
>   government at home would be, so if foreign cannon fodder **was so much
>   available the better.**

Comment: No, it means *the situation was better by that much / to that extent*.

Comment: @Minty, thanks. Is "so if foreign cannon fodder was available so much the better." an elided version? If yes, what it would be without any elision or drops?

Comment: Not really. If you try to put words in it doesn't feel as though you are putting them *back* in - it feels as though they don't really belong. It's more of a fixed phrase that's more or less equivalent to *that is/was/would be a good thing*. It may originally have been a response, as in A) *there are a lot of French troops to kill* B) *So much the better!* It has the feel of an interjection, but it can be stuck on the end of a sentence as in your example.

Comment: ... or indeed at the beginning: *So much the better if foreign cannon fodder was available; after all, there was nothing to boost the government's popularity like great mounds of dead Frenchmen rotting under the African sun*. I'd like to think times have changed BTW.

Comment: Your rewrite is not grammatical. **The original is fine but somewhat informal.** But bear in mind, the FLN was engaged, basically, in guerrilla warfare. So, I would not use cannon fodder either literally or metaphorically. The FLN did not have "canons". The writer must not be very informed about that war. Also, the use of "Frenchmen" is odd: there were French soldiers and French civilians in Algeria at the time.